# Mystery "test" text showing on page after views module update

Tags: 7, views, upgrading

I've got an instance of mystery text showing on my blog.

Here's the scenario:
I've just run the security update to 7.x-3.8 on a drupal site running 7.28 on my local machine, and didn't see this issue. When I ran the updates on the live site the issue appeared.

On the homepage blog, at the bottom of every post there is the word "test". I know it's outside of the body field tag, but I have no idea where it's coming from.
Seen here: http://susanhoodbooks.com/

I've checked the code of the view, the templates, the contents of the nodes and I can't find anything.
I'm hoping to ask for some suggestions of where I might look next before I revert the modules.
again, I haven't been able to recreate this on my local.

Please let me know if I need to supply any other information.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the DOM, it appears to be coming from Views. Since it's in a

tag, I would suggest looking to see if there is a unused field that might be the culprit.

Comment: Thank you so much for seeing what I didn't, that was the answer exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I can see there is some jquery script adding the string 'Test' for each view row [image: as shown in the attached screenshot]. Look into your code base for the string '.view-id-blog .views-field-body' and you'll find out from what file is it coming.

You may also want to disable javascript aggregation for sometime, and then see the exact file name in the developer tools directly.